# Android SDK (Eclipse) :How to Creat a Simple AlertDialog on the App Start ?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, dialog, android-alertdialog

**Hey There ,I'm totally new to Android ,I actually saw some tutorials and tried it but I still get some errors with my apps ***

So I really need to know how to create a simple `AlertDialog` when the app starts (With one Positive Button ) and asks "Are you read?"  and the button says "Yes", and after clicking yes it shall like the dialog window close and resume the app ..

I tried it but it but my app seems crash and give black screen (It was totally working until adding the Dialog )

**So here is The MainActivity Code : ***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button w;

TextView t;

EditText e;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    w = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Write);

    t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FTS);

    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text);


    w.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {


     String check1 = t.getText().toString();
     String check2 = e.getText().toString();

     if (check1.equals(check2))

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Wrote it Right !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     else if (check2.equals(""))

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It's Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     else 
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You wrote it wrong,try again !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Thanks for your time and if there is something I shall add to the Activity_Main.xml with the `Dialog` please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post this code in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this);
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Are you read?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                    "Yes"),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //your code here.
        }
                                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

there's no need for any code to dismiss the dialog as the default implementation will always dismiss the dialog on click on the button.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it did what i wanted ! :D

Answer (score 0):

use this alert box on your oncreate

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitByBackKey();

        // moveTaskToBack(false);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

protected void exitByBackKey() {

    AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Do you want to play This Game?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            //start your activiy here

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                }
            }).show();

}
```